# Customize AppVeyor's version

Tags: appveyor

I'd like to be able to specify a custom version pattern for AppVeyor's build like this:

```
version: 1.0.{build}-{branch}
```

Though there're two additional rules:

1. If a branch is master, I'd like to keep just 1.0.{build} skipping on the branch part
2. If a branch is named like features/something, I'd like to get 1.0.{build}-something in result

Is there any place in AppVeyor's pipleline where I could place those customisations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [PowerShell and CMD](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-worker-api/#update-build-details) tool to update it. You can [add script](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#script-blocks-in-build-configuration) which implements that logic in [build pipeline step](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#build-pipeline) you prefer.

2 things to remember however:

- `{build}` is a shortcut which does not work in script. You have to use `APPVEYOR_BUILD_NUMBER` [environment variable](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/environment-variables/) instead. Something like this should work for example for your first condition:`if ($env:APPVEYOR_REPO_BRANCH -eq "master") {Update-AppveyorBuild -Version 1.0.$env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_NUMBER}`
- Commit status URL can be temporary unavailable, more details [here](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/1074).